# python callback function with arguments bad practice?

Tags: python, static-typing

I wrote a listener class that executes a programmer specified callback. 
The msg is provided as a callback argument. I realized that a programmer using the class will need to look at my code to see the structure of the msg.

Is there a way of providing type hints to callback functions. Or should i refactor my callback to be a notification of a message so the programmer can invoke a get function to get the actual msg after the notification. ( IDE help works in this case but the class is a little bit harder to use )

Alternatively i could just pass something generic in the argument like dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding callback argument you can use python's `typing` module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html)). It'll be something like [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) which subscription syntax must always be used with exactly two values: the argument list and the return type:

```
def listener(callback: Callable[[int, str], int]):
    #do magic here

def callable(a: int, b: str) -> int:
    # user defined callable here
```

In this case, IDEs (like Pycharm and modern Jedi versions) will detect `Callable` typehints, and listener user won't have to look up `callback` structure.

Regarding if it's better to provide a dictionary or something else more generic is debatable and depends on actual use cases.

P.S. of course, `typing` module is not available out of the box in python2